# Erro (String de Conexao) Asp .Net MVC - Visual Studio 2013 e SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aplicação-web, exceção, visual-studio-2013, connectionstring

Estou com um problema na minha aplicação MVC Asp.Net.
Criei a String de conexão dentro do Webconfig,

```html
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connSql"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=localhost;
          Initial Catalog=CarnetAdresse;
          Integrated Security=True" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

depois criei o método GETList() dentro do Modelo "Contact" para trazer a lista do banco de dados :

```html
 public static List<Contact> GetList()
        {
            string connexionSql = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connSql"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(connexionSql))
            {
                string requete = "SELECT * FROM Contact";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(requete, cnx);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                try
                {
                    cnx.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        Contact c = new Contact();
                        c.id = (int)dataReader["id"];
                        c.Nom = (string)dataReader["Nom"];
                        c.Telephone = (string)dataReader["Telephone"];
                        c.Courriel = (string)dataReader["Courriel"];
                        c.DateNaissance = (DateTime)dataReader["DateNaissance"];
                        c.CodePostal = (string)dataReader["CodePostal"];

                        contactList.Add(c);
                    }
                    dataReader.Close();
                    return contactList;
                }
                finally
                {
                    cnx.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

e ele me dá uma exception em todo momento que tento executar o programa:

Une exception de type 'System.NullReferenceException' s'est produite dans CarnetAdresse.dll mais n'a pas été gérée dans le code utilisateur

Informations supplémentaires : **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

[image: Ele diz que string connexionSql é null]

Comment: Detalhe: Uso SQLServer 2012. No computador do professor ele utilizou SQLEXPRESS e funcionou, mas no meu nada de funcionar. Ja deletei o criei o banco de dados outras vezes, já modifiquei os nomes da string de conexao, reescrevi o código... e nada ainda

Comment: Outra coisa que tentei: Adicionei uma regra no Firewall do Windows para permitir a porta 1433 para o SQL SERVER. Firewall allow port 1433 for SQL Server
Link:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2011/06/how-to-open-firewall-port-1433-for-sql-server-database-engine-for-use-with-scom-or-anything-else/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem dois web.config numa aplicação web .net. Um dentro da raiz da aplicação e outro na raiz da pasta views. Esse código está em qual web.config? O certo é estar no web.config da raiz da aplicação.

Comment: Resolvido. O código estava no webconfig fora da raiz. Obrigado.